# Running Rails Server - Webpacker installation

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, ruby, yarnpkg

I've followed the Setup Ruby on Rails instructions detailed on: https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.14-mojave , but I'm having issues with getting the Rails server running...

```
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-darwin18]
Michaels-MBP:myapp mh$ rbenv versions
  system
* 2.7.1 (set by /Users/mh/myapp/.ruby-version)
Michaels-MBP:myapp mh$ rails -v
Rails 6.0.3.2
```

when running:

```
rails server
```

I end up with:

```
/Users/mh/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:95:in `rescue in load': Webpacker configuration file not found /Users/mh/myapp/config/webpacker.yml. Please run rails webpacker:install Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/mh/myapp/config/webpacker.yml (RuntimeError)
```

running the rails webpacker install gives me:

```
sh: node: command not found
sh: nodejs: command not found
Node.js not installed. Please download and install Node.js https://nodejs.org/en/download/
```

I've already installed the Node.js using the website installer.pkg, and get the following:

```
Michaels-MBP:myapp mh$ brew install yarn
Updating Homebrew...
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/node-14.4.0.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://akamai.bintray.com/06/06ef204701e93bbcf3909dba4ac9d3ca1d4df
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/1.22.4/yarn-v1.22.4.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com/499
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Installing dependencies for yarn: node
==> Installing yarn dependency: node
==> Pouring node-14.4.0.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/node
Target /usr/local/bin/node
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/node'

Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall node`
==> Caveats
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/node/14.4.0: 4,659 files, 60.8MB
==> Installing yarn
  /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4: 14 files, 5MB, built in 2 seconds
==> Caveats
==> node
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
Michaels-MBP:myapp mh$ brew link --overwrite node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/14.4.0... 
Error: Could not symlink include/node/common.gypi
/usr/local/include/node is not writable.
Michaels-MBP:myapp mh$ brew postinstall node
==> Postinstalling node
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall node`
```

It said something in the Yarn installation about the shims being 'before' the rbenv shims in PATH? I'm not sure what that means...

Here's a copy of my PATH - which I know is probably messed up...

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"

alias laptop='bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/monfresh/laptop/master/laptop)'



eval "$(hub alias -s)"

if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi

export PATH="$HOME/.bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem like this:

- Using Homebrew

```
    $ brew install node
```

- Then install webpacker

```
    $ rails webpacker:install
```

- Make sure all packages are up to date

```
    $ yarn install --check-files
```

- And... Good luck, Start your Rails server

```
    $ rails s
```

Comment: You don't have permissions to write. Try with: **$ sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local/include/node** Or try to give permissions to write the include folder. And try again.

Comment: Yes... that's what i was thinking :)  !Come on you almost got it!

Comment: AND HE CAN SEE THE PAGE AT LOCAL HOST:3000
For the record, it's taken about 4 hours to get this working.
Thanks Toni, it's all downhill from here right...?

Comment: That's great! I hope so :')